# Local ring of an affine curve $K$ at a point $p\in K$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, local-rings

I'm reading A Royal Road to Algebraic Geometry by Holme. The book defines the local ring as follows:

> The local ring of $K$ at $P=(a,b)$ is the ring 
>   $$\mathcal{O}_{K,P}=\Gamma(K)_{\mathfrak{m}(a,b)},$$
>   where $\Gamma(K)$ is the coordinate ring of the curve $K$.

I know there must be something obvious I am missing. I am very confused with this definition. I understand that essentially the local ring at a point $P$ is the set of functions $\frac{f}{g}$ where $f,g\in \Gamma(K)$, and $g(P)\ne 0$.

But in this definition, the symbol $\Gamma(K)_{\mathfrak{m}(a,b)}$ means the set of the functions of the form $\frac{f}{g}$, $f\in \Gamma(K), g\in \mathfrak{m}(a,b)$. So this means $g(P)$ must be zero.

Could someone explain what I am missing? Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are absolutely right in your understanding, and  the notation means what you say, namely that $g\notin \mathfrak m (a,b)$ i.e; that $g(P)\neq 0$. In other words the notation does not mean what you think it means :-) I agree that this standard notation is a bit confusing, but it is too late to change it now.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Is that right?! Thank you so much for clarifying this then! I've been thinking about it for a while. In fact I picked up what I thought from Gathmann's notes, where $R_f$ stands for the localization of $R$ at $S=\{f^n\}$. Maybe this is what user26857 meant. Holme's book uses this notation at the same page, where $\Gamma^+(C)_{x_0}$ is used to represent $\{\frac{P(x_0,x_1,x_2)}{x_0^n}\}$. Aren't these two notations confusing...

Comment: The notations in this context are rather confusing: $R_f$ means you may divide by $f$ (and its powers) whereas $R_\mathfrak m$ means you may divide by elements **not** in $\mathfrak m$ but you must not divide by elements of $\mathfrak m$ !

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: I see now. Very interesting.:) Thank you!